# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined when importing store from js module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I am trying to import a vuex store into a custom js module in my vuex app.  I've tried this many different ways, and each time the build says it's complied 100%, but I am receiving the following error from the browser console, and nothing is loaded to the browser.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined
```

I've tried importing it multiple ways, but they all return the same error response in the console.

```
import store from '../store'
import { store } from '../store'
import store from '../store/index.js'
```

And I've tried calling the store multiple ways including:

```
let tokens = store.state.user.tokens
let tokens = store.getters['user/getTokens']
```

My store file looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import user from './modules/user'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    user
  }
})

export default store
```

Here's the code for the store/modules/user.js file..

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    user: {},
    active: false,
    tokens: {},
  },

  mutations: {
    updateUser(state, user) {
      state.user = user.details
      state.active = true
      state.tokens = user.tokens
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async updateUser({ commit }) {
      try {
        const res = await axios().get('/user/details') // I've taken out the axios deatils here
        commit('updateUser', res.data.user)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    },
  },
}
```

I'm not really sure what's going on.  I've done this successfully in another application, but for some reason this one isn't working as expected, and as I mentioned, it's not even loading the application into the browser, it's just failing with this error.  Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the 'user' Vuex module code to your question>

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code, difficult to diagnose.  I just created a sample Vuex module, store, and Vue component and it is working.

user-store-module.js

```
const userModule = {
  state: () => ({
    users: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Tim'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Debbie'
      }
    ]
  }),
}

export default userModule;
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import userModule from './user-store-module.js'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    userModule: userModule
  }
})
```

VuexModule.js (Vue 2 with Vue CLI)

```
<template>
  <div class="vuex-module">
    <h3>Users</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>NAME</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
              <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
              <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      users() {
        return this.$store.state.userModule.users;
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I've added an example of my user.js store module code in my original question.  I am not having any issues retrieving this code from a Vue file.  The issue is trying to get this info from a custom js module.

Comment: I think I understand that you are trying to import your Vuex store into a custom js module, but what is the relationship between the custom module and your overall (Vue?) application.  Maybe someone else will help.  A CodeSandbox version of your app wouldn't hurt.